# confirm dialog box in php

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have this echo statement:

```
echo "<td align=center style=border:0>"."<a href='?delete=$row[id]'>Delete</a>"."</td>";
```

how am I able to make that when I press the 'Delete' a yes no dialog box will appear?

I've read somewhere that it can add some thing like this somewhere in the statement:

```
onClick="javascript:return confirm(\'Are you sure you want to delete this record?\')"
```

Any help would be appreciated.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
echo "<td align=center style=border:0><a onclick='return confirm(\"Are you sure you want to delete this record?\")' href='?delete=$row[id]'>Delete</a></td>";
```

I got rid of the unnecessary `"."` in your original code.

Answer (score 0):

Just Use this

```
echo "<td align=center style=border:0><a onclick='return confirm(\"Are you sure you want to delete this record?\")' href='?delete=$row[id]'>Delete</a></td>";
```

Instead of

```
echo "<td align=center style=border:0>"."<a href='?delete=$row[id]'>Delete</a>"."</td>";
```